# Replace linux dynamic loader in bazel run/test execution

Tags: go, bazel, ld, glibc, cgo

I have an issue writing a custom wrapper around `go_test` from [rules_go](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/core/rules.md#go_test):
My situation: I have a set of precompiled libraries (.so) for Fedora that I want to link against go code using cgo. This part works beautifully. The resulting binaries run correctly on Fedora.
I even have declared all of the libraries as dependencies correctly and they show up in the runfiles of my `go_binary` outputs.
The precompiled .so files also include glibc from fedora (this is required since the other shared libraries depend on this version of the glibc) and `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` from Fedora.

How would I write a wrapper around `go_test` that uses the vendored ld from Fedora as a binary and passes the original go binary path as the first argument?

Additional info:

All of the libraries are accessible via the runfiles and findable via the ELF runpath. It's only ld itself that is selected incorrectly:

```
$ readelf -a bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test | grep RUNPATH
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs:$ORIGIN/initserver_test.runfiles/__main__/_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs]

$ ldd bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f944795d000)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff66347000)
libargon2.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libargon2.so.1 (0x00007f9447952000)
libblkid.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f9447919000)
libc.so.6 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libc.so.6 (0x00007f944773c000)
libcrypto.so.3 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f9447312000)
libcryptsetup.so.12 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libcryptsetup.so.12 (0x00007f9447294000)
libdevmapper.so.1.02 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libdevmapper.so.1.02 (0x00007f9447238000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9447218000)
libjson-c.so.5 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libjson-c.so.5 (0x00007f9447205000)
libm.so.6 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9447123000)
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f9447086000)
libpthread.so.0 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9447081000)
libselinux.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9447054000)
libssl.so.3 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libssl.so.3 (0x00007f9446fb1000)
libudev.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f9446f81000)
libuuid.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f9446f78000)
libz.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9446f5e000)

$ bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f637dec7000)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2e1e8000)
libargon2.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libargon2.so.1 (0x00007f637debc000)
libblkid.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f637de83000)
libc.so.6 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libc.so.6 (0x00007f637dca6000)
libcrypto.so.3 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f637d87c000)
libcryptsetup.so.12 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libcryptsetup.so.12 (0x00007f637d7fe000)
libdevmapper.so.1.02 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libdevmapper.so.1.02 (0x00007f637d7a2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f637d782000)
libjson-c.so.5 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libjson-c.so.5 (0x00007f637d76f000)
libm.so.6 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libm.so.6 (0x00007f637d68d000)
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f637d5f0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f637d5eb000)
libselinux.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f637d5be000)
libssl.so.3 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libssl.so.3 (0x00007f637d51b000)
libudev.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f637d4eb000)
libuuid.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f637d4e2000)
libz.so.1 => /some/path/bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/../../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/libz.so.1 (0x00007f637d4c8000)
```

When using `bazel run` or `bazel test` on Ubuntu, my host `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is used and I get a segfault. This is due to the hardcoded path to the interpreter (LD) embedded in the go binary and because ld and libc have to match:

```
readelf -p .interp bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test

String dump of section '.interp':
[     0]  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

```
bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The same works if I execute fedoras `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` directly and give it the path to the go binary as an argument (this is equivalent to setting the interpreter in the elf header to the absolute path of the location of the fedora ld on my host).

```
bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test.runfiles/__main__/_solib_k8/_U_S_Srpm_Ccryptsetup___Urpm_Scryptsetup-libs/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 bazel-bin/bootstrapper/internal/initserver/initserver_test_/initserver_test
PASS
```